# Increase in number and show that number in entry box

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I created global variable name count

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
from csv import DictWriter, DictReader

data_label_frame=tk.LabelFrame()
data_label_frame.pack()

LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana' , 16,'bold')
global count
count=0
class sea_of_btc(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self , *args , **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args , **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top" , fill = "both" , expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0 , weight =1 )
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0 , weight =1)
        self.config(background='#FAEBEF')
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (start_page , page_one ):
            frame = F(container , self)
            self.frames [F] = frame
            frame.grid (row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky= "nsew")
        self.show_frame(start_page)


    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        return frame

class start_page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self , parent , controller ):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

Here now I want that whenever register_func will be called there will be increase in number count and after that whenever I open the frame it show me that number in entry box and user can not change that number means that it just work for the serial number to show in entry box

```
class page_one (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        registration_number = tk.Label(data_label_frame, text = 'Registration No :', font = LARGE_FONT)
        registration_number.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5  , pady=5 , sticky =tk.W )

        registration_number_var=tk.StringVar()
        registration_number_entry = ttk.Entry(data_label_frame,width = 5, font=LARGE_FONT ,textvariable=registration_number_var,
                                              )

        registration_number_entry.grid(row =1, column =0,padx=10,pady=10 , ipady=5 , sticky=tk.E)

        def register_fucn():
            count += 1
            with open('new.csv', 'a', newline='') as data_file:
                dict_writer = DictWriter(data_file, fieldnames=['Registration No',
                                                               ])
        registar_btn = ttk.Button(data_label_frame , text ='Registar' ,command= register_fucn)
        registar_btn.grid(row=2 , column=1, sticky =tk.E , padx=10 , pady=10,ipady=5)
```

Comment: `global count` is not to be used outside the function, you have to use it inside like `def function(): global count`

Comment: Read up on [Python Classes and Objects, Section "The self|Class and Instance Variables"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/) and [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try using global inside the function

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
from csv import DictWriter, DictReader

data_label_frame=tk.LabelFrame()
data_label_frame.pack()

LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana' , 16,'bold')
count = 0
class sea_of_btc(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self , *args , **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args , **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top" , fill = "both" , expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0 , weight =1 )
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0 , weight =1)
        self.config(background='#FAEBEF')
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (start_page , page_one ):
            frame = F(container , self)
            self.frames [F] = frame
            frame.grid (row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky= "nsew")
        self.show_frame(start_page)


    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        return frame

class start_page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self , parent , controller ):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


class page_one (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        registration_number = tk.Label(data_label_frame, text = 'Registration No :', font = LARGE_FONT)
        registration_number.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5  , pady=5 , sticky =tk.W )

        registration_number_var=tk.StringVar()
        registration_number_entry = ttk.Entry(data_label_frame,width = 5, font=LARGE_FONT ,textvariable=registration_number_var,
                                              )

        registration_number_entry.grid(row =1, column =0,padx=10,pady=10 , ipady=5 , sticky=tk.E)

        def register_fucn():
            global count
            count += 1
            with open('new.csv', 'a', newline='') as data_file:
                dict_writer = DictWriter(data_file, fieldnames=['Registration No',
                                                               ])
        registar_btn = ttk.Button(data_label_frame , text ='Registar' ,command= register_fucn)
        registar_btn.grid(row=2 , column=1, sticky =tk.E , padx=10 , pady=10,ipady=5)
```

Comment: How can I show this number in entry box(registration_number_entry) in (read-only) state , means that a person just can see the number but can't change it

Comment: disable the entry everytime after you change it's value

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to make the user unable to change the number in the `Entry` widget while increasing the number each time, when the `Button` is pressed.

- **Globalize** the variable storing the number you want to show, inside the function.
- Change the **`state`** of the `Entry` widget to **`NORMAL`** after globalizing the variable.
- **Increase** the variable as much you want.
- Then **`insert`** the variable inside the `Entry` widget.
- Finally, change the **`state`** of the `Entry` widget to **`DISABLED`**.

Like I have done in this **Example:**

```
import tkinter as tk

var = 10


def func(en):
    global var

    en.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)

    en.delete(0, tk.END)
    var = var + 1
    en.insert(0, var)
    en.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)


root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text='Click', command=lambda: func(e))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please give your example according to my code because I tried it but it is not working

Comment: this function just called one time only for example if i click again and again on register it will not increase the value ,

Comment: how it can increase in number if I want to click again and again function

Comment: For example I set a variable count=0 then whenever I click on click button it increase one number in entry box and store that number in entry box

Comment: @PakistanBeauty I have edited the answer. Somewhat according to your needs. Please make sure to accept the answer if it works for you. :)